# Java- Calling paint() method from window() method in another class?

Tags: java, graphics, window, frame, paint

I have a Game class which should call a Die class to draw several die. The problem is I do not know how to call the paint method (and all the other methods in the Die class for the matter) which is in the Die class from within the Game class. I create the window in the Game class which usually calls the paint method by using `setVisible(true)`, but it won't call it if it is in a different class.
Here part of the Die class:

```js
public class Die 
{ 
 private int xA, yA;     
 private int dieNumber;   
 
 public void setup(int someX, int someY, int someValue) {
  dieNumber = someValue;
  xA = someX;
  yA = someY;
  
 }

 public void paint(Graphics pane) { 
  
  drawBlank(pane);    

  if (dieNumber == 1){   
   drawOne(pane); } 
  else if (dieNumber == 2){
   drawTwo(pane); }
  ...
 }


 private void drawBlank(Graphics pane)
 {  
  final int WIDTH = 56; 
  final int HEIGHT = 56; 
  
  pane.setColor(Color.black);  
  pane.drawRect(xA, yA, WIDTH , HEIGHT); 

  pane.drawLine(xA-15, yA-10, xA, yA); 
  pane.drawLine(xA-15, yA-10, xA+40, yA-10); 
  ...
 }

 
 private void drawOne(Graphics pane) { 
  drawDot(pane, xA+28, yA+28);  
 }

 
 private void drawTwo(Graphics pane) {
      }
.....
```

And here is part of the Game class

```js
public class Game extends Frame 
{
 private Die myDie, theComputerDie;
 private int dieNumber;
 private int comDieValue;
 
 
 }

 

 public void window()
 { 
  setTitle("Roll the dice"); 
  setLocation(100, 100);   
  setSize(900, 600);    
  setBackground(Color.lightGray); 
  setVisible(true); 
  
  theComputerDie = new Die();
  myDie = new Die();
  myDie.setup(x, y, dieNumber);
  theComputerDie.setup(comX, comY, comDieValue);
      
  values();
  rules();
  
 }
.....
```

Comment: This looks like Java; why is it tagged JavaScript?

Comment: @Mathletics my mistake, just removed that tag.

Comment: So, what happens if you call myDie.paint(whateverPane) etc?

Comment: @RealSkeptic it tells me pane can not be resolved to a variable.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Let me ask a different way. I can always just call the setup() method from the Game class, is there a way to then call the paint() method from the setup method?